# Cannot change collation on my MySQL database for all tables - please help

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x

I have MAMP installed on my Macbook, I open up phpMyAdmin and go to Operations, I choose the Collation that I need to use for my WordPress site. I then click "GO", but when I run the following query it still shows the old Collation, not the new one I need.

Is there some MySQL query I can run that will change the collation for me on all my tables?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

If you run the following SQL query, it will produce a list of ALTER TABLE statements that you can then paste in the "Run SQL Query" in phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT ('ALTER TABLE `', tbl.`TABLE_SCHEMA`, '`.`', tbl.`TABLE_NAME`, '` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;') FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` tbl WHERE tbl.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'dbase'
```

The list will then produce as many ALTER TABLE statements as there are tables that you have.

So for instance, it will produce something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `dbname`.`tablename` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Then, you just copy/past that ALTER TABLE in the Run SQL Query windows and run it.